# Issue in scrolling to right element (React Class Component)

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, scroll

So I've been having issues in getting the window to scroll at all, let alone to a specific spot. I eventually was able to get the window to actually scroll using this:

```
$("html").animate({ scrollTop: 1000 }, 500);
```

but now I'm wanting to scroll to a specific div marked with an ID. I also believe I have to follow this above method of using animate with a timer delay as most other solutions using `.scrollTo` , `.scrollTop` , or `.scrollIntoView` did not work. I think the issue with these not working involves an overflow being set to hidden but I can't modify the CSS to be otherwise at this point so I'm using this animate method as it has been the only one to actually move the window scroll.

One thing I tried doing was assigning a tag to a test element at the bottom of the page and doing this:

```
$("html").animate({ scrollTop: $('#test').offset().top }, 500);
```

but this would only barely scroll the window down, while `#test` is a div at the very bottom of the page.

I'm not sure if this is something that would also interfere with scrolling, but the content above this `#test` div within the page is a div that contains TabPanes with content that isn't always the same size. Either way, how can I scroll from the top to a specific tag if not doing the above?

Comment: Can you should your code, It's really hard to say what is wrong without seeing actual application. Please try to reproduce the issue and create a demo on a site like [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [CodePen](https://codepen.io/). Test if the issue is related to React (I don't see any React code in the question) or if it's only in your CSS. Also please explain what "did not work" means, what is the exact code that you tried and what effect did you get. And check your console if you don't get any errors.